# c++ How to exit a function that calls itself?

Tags: c++, function

```
void function ()
{
    if (condition)
    {
        //  do something
    }
    else if (other condition)
    {
        //  go back to main()
    }
    function();
}
```

In here, the function will always call itself, no matter what I replace 'go back to main()' with.

```
return;
exit;
break;
```

The code above does not work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE] please?

Comment: There is no "go back to main" - when you `return` out of a function it goes back to the caller (which in this case is most likely a recursive call)

Comment: you must never **unconditionally** call function itself

Comment: `return` should have gotten you out of one call. Can't speak for how many calls deep you got. Lots of nasty things can happen with recursion.

Comment: Make sure that your condition doesn't always evaluate to true, eg if you mistype `=` for `==`.

Comment: Like usual, it *returns*. And all parent calls in the call-stack *also* returns.

Comment: May I recommend executing your code with a debugger?  With a debugger you can control the execution of the program, running it instruction by instruction if you have to get that low-level, and view the variables as you go. I'd put a breakpoint at the beginning of `function` and then start stepping to see what's really going on.

Comment: When using recursion, it's helpful (especially to the maintainer who follows you) always to clearly document the part of the code that makes sure recursion eventually terminates.  I realize you posted pseudo-code, but this point is still relevant to your question.

Comment: really every compiler must make [warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4717?view=vs-2017) for this code - *`function' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow*

Comment: I'm pretty sure the goal was to get the hell out of Dodge at `go back to main()`, so it's not intended to be unconditional. @UnholySheep probably gave the best response of any of us.

Comment: `return;` [certainly **would work**](https://www.ideone.com/sTYnXD) in your pseudocode.  After returning from `function()`, there is no more logic to perform in any of the recursions.

Answer (score 1):

Terrible answer:

```
setjmp();
longjmp();
```

Comment: Could also throw an exception while you're at it!

Comment: @Xaqq technically that’s the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your problem is the `if {} else if`, which does not cover every case. Typically recursion is something like this:

```
void function () {
    if (condition) {
        function();
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `else` branch seems unnecessary. A `void` function returns when it reaches the end of the function body.

Comment: And also upvoted. This question's currently not in good enough condition to get good answers. What you've given is good general advice, but I'd recommend holding off until you can do better.

Comment: I explicitly left the `else` and `return` to make it clear how this is related to OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really going back to `main()`.That's not your choice. `return` sends the control back to the caller function. The circumstance under which your code would have worked perfectly fine was that it never reached the recursive call at all. That is, if it reached the `else` block and returned to the caller, that is, `main`.

But from the second time onwards, the caller is no longer `main()`. Rather, the caller is the function itself. So, starting from the second time onwards, even if the condition does not match, it will return to the function itself and the function will be called again thereafter.